# meshprop npm module crashes with no way to try/catch exception

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-gyp

When a non-supported file format such as a png is analyzed, the node server crashes and this error pops up:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::length_error: vector
Abort trap: 6
```

Even when the relevant code is try/catch'ed, the error is not caught. What is a way to catch this error and prevent it from crashing the server?

the file being given to it is always renamed with a format that has .stl at the end.

```
try {

crashes here --->        meshprop.parse("renamedfile.stl", function(err, props) {
...(callback that never gets called with the .png)
}
}
catch(err)
{
console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: could you show the code? else i would try starting it in a separate process and let it crash there.

Comment: @RolandStarke I have, but it's not anything unique. It doesn't even callback the function, just crashes immediately